# Not able to update my browser from Internet Explorer-8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2003

I inherited a neglected system with an old fileserver running Server 2003 with Internet Explorer 8. Now I need to do some basic updates in order to migrate to a newer server but I can't update IE 8 because I can't use IE8 to browse to a site to download something more current. Am I permanently stuck in this catch-22?

Answer (score 0):

In the Start Menu right click on my Computer and click Properties > Automatic Updates Tab > Download and Choose.
Then Go to the Group Policies and go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Here Specifiy an Internal Path to:
http://wsus.gimme.money:8530 for both settings
Restart the Server.
Then Type in Run:
wuauclt /detectnow
After some Time your Server should Display a Yellow Shield with an Expclamation Mark
and it is for Updates Download and Install these Updates.<
This Works because you will be using a Distant WSUS